# Hanoi Tower Variation: Place Maximum Number of Balls on $N$ Pegs

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, upper-bound, towers-of-hanoi

**Problem Statement.** There are many interesting variations on the Tower of Hanoi problem. This version consists of $N$ pegs and one ball containing each number from $1, 2, 3, \dots$ Whenever the sum of the numbers on two balls is **not** a perfect square (i.e., $c^2$ for some integer $c$), they will repel each other with such force that they can never touch each other.[image]

The player must place balls on the pegs one by one, in order of increasing ball number (i.e., first ball $1$, then ball $2$, ball $3$ $\dots$). The game ends where there is no non-repelling move. The goal is to place as many balls on the pegs as possible. The figure above gives a best possible result for $N = 4$ pegs. One may assume $N \le 50$ in all test cases.

Source: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1217.

I originally encountered this problem in the book "Programming Challenges" from Skiena and Revilla where it is part of Chapter 9: "Graph Traversal"  given a short hint:

> Can the constraints be usefully modeled using a DAG?

**Question 1.** How to use this hint?

Last but not least, I observed the solution seems to be always

$\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{(N + 1)^2}{2} \right\rfloor - 1$

which is the reason I ask this question.

**Question 2.** How to prove this formula or at least some upper bound on the number of balls depending on $N$?

I appreciate any kind of help in getting more out of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: As for the hint, I think they're aiming at the fact that the relation '$a+b$ is a perfect square and $a>b$' on the numbers $1,2,\ldots,k$ leads to a DAG. 
As for the summation, you could for instance try checking whether you can sometimes choose multiple balls to stack on and whether it is optimal to stack on a ball when you can.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the problem link. Yes, the goal is to determine the maximum number of balls for a given value of $N$. I already thought of the mentioned DAG. It may be the case that some vertices have out-degree > 1, i.e. it's not clear how to split the vertices in optimal stacks.